# Help with simple check for Oracle Dataguard on 19c

Tags: oracle, dataguard

I am new to Oracle and needing help just getting a quick script to check Oracle Dataguard. Do any of you have a simple script that could be used to just give me a quick status on dataguard? Just a quick check, if dataguard is in sync or not.

I was given the below query, and it appears the script just simply tells the log gap count between the primary and stand by. Does that seem reasonable or is there a better approach? In this case, if the log gap is more than say, 3, then dataguard needs to be investigated?

```sql
select LOG_ARCHIVED-LOG_APPLIED "LOG_GAP" from
(SELECT MAX(SEQUENCE#) LOG_ARCHIVED FROM V$ARCHIVED_LOG WHERE DEST_ID=1 AND ARCHIVED='YES'),
(SELECT MAX(SEQUENCE#) LOG_APPLIED FROM V$ARCHIVED_LOG WHERE DEST_ID=2 AND APPLIED='YES');
```

Answer (score 0):

Log switches - by default - are not bound to a time limit, meaning a lag of 3 sequences could mean a lag of 3 minutes or 3 hours as well. Periodic log switches can be forced by setting the [ARCHIVE_LAG_TARGET](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/ARCHIVE_LAG_TARGET.html) parameter.

But it is better to query [V$DATAGUARD_STATS](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/V-DATAGUARD_STATS.html) on the standby that reports the lag in seconds. Something like:

```
select
  name,
  value,
  time_computed
from
 v$dataguard_stats
where
  name in ('apply lag', 'transport lag')
;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help.